# Rows printing current month and then remaining months of the year

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'd like to make a query that shows the current month in text form and then the rest of the year printed on the following rows until all months for the year have been printed.

This is somewhat hard to explain so I've made the following example. I know the following code is ridiculous but this is the only way I know to do this with my current skill level. Ideally I would also like months to be converted from printing an integer to print the character value of the month (so 1 would be January). I know I could do this with a case/when but I'm sure there's a better way that I haven't been exposed to yet.

```
declare @currentmonth as int = datepart(month, getdate())
select
    @currentmonth
union
select
    @currentmonth +1
union
select
    @currentmonth +2
union
select
    @currentmonth +3
union
select
    @currentmonth +4
union
select
    @currentmonth +5
union
select
    @currentmonth +6
union
select
    @currentmonth +7
union
select
    @currentmonth +8
union
select
    @currentmonth +9
union
select
    @currentmonth +10
union
select
    @currentmonth +11
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL Server 2008+ you can use this

```
SELECT v.i
FROM (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)) v(i)
WHERE v.i>=MONTH(GETDATE())
```

Comment: This feature is called the Row Constructor. It is a great feature. However huge number of inserts done with this feature will suffer a performance hit as opposed to the regular way. [Related article](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/508112/insert-performance-of-row-constructor-is-quiet-bad)

Answer (score 3):

A chance to use common table expression (SQL Server 2005+):

```
declare @adate datetime
set @adate = '2011-07-31'

;with clndr(m) as (
    select @adate
    union all
    select dateadd(month, 1, m)
    from clndr
    where datepart(year, dateadd(month, 1, m)) = datepart(year, @adate)
)
select datename(month, m)
from clndr
```

Answer (score 1):

With Common table expression you can easily write the code

```
    DECLARE @currentmonth INT
    SET @currentmonth=datepart(month, getdate())
    ;WITH CTE AS
    (SELECT @currentmonth AS currentmonth 
       UNION ALL 
     SELECT currentmonth +1 FROM CTE WHERE currentmonth <10
    )

    SELECT * FROM CTE
```

Comment: Copying another answer... Really?

Comment: @Michael You should see the sql statments and then make a remark like that .The only thing which is common in both the SQL is the use of CTE but the logic is completely different